# elm get-started documentation "cannot find module"

Tags: elm

Hello I just follow the doc from: http://elm-lang.org/get-started but
I'm blocked in the finding module part:

```
$ mkdir elm
$ cd elm
$ elm package install
  Some new packages are needed. Here is the upgrade plan.

    Install:
      elm-lang/core 4.0.1

  Do you approve of this plan? (y/n) y
  Downloading elm-lang/core
  Packages configured successfully!
```

I get some simple example:

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elm-lang/elm-lang.org/master/src/examples/buttons.elm
  ... Enregistre : «buttons.elm»

  buttons.elm            100%[===========================>]     495  --.-KB/s    in 0s
  2016-05-26 09:32:19 (150 MB/s) - «buttons.elm» enregistré [495/495]
```

I get a missing module  Errror:

```
$ elm-make buttons.elm
  I cannot find module 'Html'.

  Module 'Main' is trying to import it.

  Potential problems could be:
    * Misspelled the module name
    * Need to add a source directory or new dependency to elm-package.json
  (venv)luis@spinoza:~/lab/sandbox/elm
$
```

I can't find where in the documentation is explain the connexion from

```
import xxx Exposing yyy
```

And the equivalent of

```
$ pip install xxx
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the `elm-lang/html` package using `elm package install elm-lang/html`.

To find out which package you need when you receive such an eror from the compiler, you could go to http://package.elm-lang.org/ and, doing a little search, finding out which package is exposing the module you need by looking in the right column when you are in the details of a package.

For example [here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.0.0/) you'll see that the `elm-lang/html` package is exposing the following modules: `Html`, `Html.App`, `Html.Attributes`, `Html.Events` and `Html.Lazy`.

There is also [an issue](https://github.com/elm-lang/error-message-catalog/issues/118) asking to improve the connection between the module and the package that is exposing it, so the compiler could help more during project bootstrap